# How to set noindex and nofollow metas in symfony framework?

Tags: symfony1, meta-tags, nofollow, noindex

I am using symfony 1.0.6 and site structure is as below;

apps/frontend/module/custompages

I want to set 'noindex and nofollow' metas to pages of custompages module.

I tried giving as below:

```
metas:
  robots: noindex,nofollow
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Assuming you cleared the cache? Also, make sure there isn't a view.yml in the module that would override the default view.yml in the app config.

Comment: there is a view.yml in module. mymodule name is 'custompages' and I have added metas in custompages/config/view.yml. Isn't right?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you forget the parent "default" container in your view.yml file?

```
default:
  metas:
    robots: noindex,nofollow
```